# unable to run playwright test with angular - ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '@playwright/test'

Tags: angular, playwright, angular-test

We upgraded our angular 12 app to 14 and then realized that the playwright tests are no longer running. Initially I thought it must have been the upgrade so I tried to track back by creating a new angular 12 app and trying to run default tests, but it failed as well with same error.

Steps to reproduce:

1. nvm install 14.15.0
2. nvm use 14.15.0
3. mkdir angular12
4. cd angular12
5. npm install @angular/cli@12
6. ./node_modules/.bin/ng new playwright-test
7. cd playwright-test
8. npm init playwright@latest
9. npx playwright test OR ./node_modules/.bin/playwright test

On install prompts I selected all the default values.

I get following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/@playwright/test'
    at Object.statSync (fs.js:1086:3)
    at fileExists (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/util.js:319:38)
    at resolveImportSpecifierExtension (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/util.js:302:7)
    at resolveHook (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/transform/transform.js:118:68)
    at Function.resolveFilename (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/transform/transform.js:188:24)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/playwright.config.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module.f._compile (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/utilsBundleImpl.js:16:994)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.i.<computed>.ut._extensions.<computed> (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/utilsBundleImpl.js:16:1010)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at requireOrImport (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/transform/transform.js:172:20)
    at requireOrImportDefaultObject (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/common/configLoader.js:121:53)
    at ConfigLoader.loadConfigFile (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/common/configLoader.js:94:26)
    at runTests (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/cli.js:118:55)
    at i.<anonymous> (/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/cli.js:40:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'stat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/shrede01/projects/tmp/angular12/playwright-test/@playwright/test'
}
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "playwright-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.18",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.37.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

I can't figure out what is causing this since I think I am following the documentation correctly. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run from inside playwright root folder- "npx playwright test " on the command prompt?

Comment: Interesting when I run 'cd node_modules/@playwright && npx playwright test', from the application folder, I get 'Error: No tests found'

Comment: I think its unable to find test because it cannot find the config so I ran 
npx playwright test --config="./../../playwright.config.ts" from folder "node_modules/@playwright" and now again its giving me the same error

Comment: If you place your Playwright code in a simple directory path like "C:\Playwright" and execute , does it works?

Comment: It seems its just an path issue due to overly complicated folder structure. Its not finding stuff where it suppose to.

Comment: nope no difference when moved to root(non nested) folder.

Answer (score 0):

got answer from @dgozman in github issues https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/27065

Issue was caused because the playwright didn't support the node version I was using. I was able to get it working with node 16 with angular 14.